# JSON.parse does not work to convert string as expected when reading from cookie

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, cookies, google-tag-manager

I have read through the most common problem areas found here when it comes to JSON.parse, replaced my single quotes with double quotes but still...

Anyway here is the deal.

I am storing my object in a cookie.

It looks like this:

`{"all": [{...},{...},{...}]}`

where {...} has more key value pairs with text and numbers

I use a Google Tag Manager Cookie Variable to read from the Cookie.

It gives me a string of '[object Object]'

So far so good.

When I try to use JSON.parse testing different ways in the console) I always get the same error and don't know why.

> Error:
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `{"all": [{...},{...},{...}]}` a string? It looks like you're trying to parse a JS Object, not JSON

Comment: `[object Object]` is not valid JSON (the `o` is invalid at that position and that's what the error tells you). If you want to store an object as a string you have to call `JSON.stringify` first.

Comment: Also if you do NOT need the data at the server, use localStorage or sessionStorage and you still need to JSON.stringify before storing